# Simple animation with mathematica

Tags: plotting, animation

I have just started to learn Mathematica. I want to see how can I generate animations in Mathematica. For example, the I want to plot an equation $$x(t)=5\cos(10t)\tag{1}$$ which I can do. But suppose I interpret $t$ as the time, and $x(t)$ the position of the particle at time $t$, how can I generate an animation which showing a ball changing its position with time according to (1)?

Comment: Have a look at the command `PointPlot` and `Manipulate` or `Animate`.

Comment: Take a look at e.g. [How do I know the calculation time of an equation solving?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169815/how-do-i-know-the-calculation-time-of-an-equation-solving/169819#169819)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher What is `PointPlot`? I don't have in my MMA, and I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ListPlot`. *facepalm*

Comment: Wel have had quite a few question like this before. Look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30161 or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63689 or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161690

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Animate[
  Show[
    Plot[5 Cos[10 u], {u, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 10],
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{t, 5 Cos[10 t]}]}]
  ],
  {t, 0, Pi}
]
```

[image]

Comment: With `Point[Dynamic@{t, 5 Cos[10 t]}]` only coordinates will need to be updated instead of the whole plot.